# polynomial Assignment through file in C

Tags: c, file-io, polynomials

I want to assign the exponent and coefficient information input from the file to the circular linked list.

file "a.txt" is as follows

```
8 3
7 2
3 0
```

However, there are also strange values ​​in the output like this. I wanted to make the list circular, but it doesn't.

```
coef    expon 
3       0
7       2
8       3
7887744 0
7900240 0
7864656 0
7869712 0
7900240 0
7864656 0
7869712 0
```

please, I can't find the solution.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct polyNode* polyPointer;
typedef struct polyNode{
    int  coef;
    int expon;
    polyPointer link;
};

int main()  {
    polyPointer A, B, C = (polyPointer)malloc(sizeof(polyPointer)) ;
    FILE *fa, *fb ;
    int a;

    fa = fopen("a.txt", "r");
    if(fa==NULL){
        printf("file open error\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if(fb==NULL){
        printf("file open error\n");
        return 1;    
    }
    A = create_circle_linked_poly(fa);
    printf("coef        expon\n");
    int i;
    for(A; i<10; A=A->link, i++)
        printf("%d  %d\n", A->coef, A->expon); 
    return 0;
}

polyPointer create_circle_linked_poly(FILE *a){
    polyPointer head = malloc(sizeof(polyPointer));
    polyPointer temp = malloc(sizeof(polyPointer));
    first = head;
    int res;
    while(1){
        polyPointer p =(polyPointer) malloc(sizeof(polyPointer));
        res = fscanf(a, "%d %d", &p->coef, &p->expon);
        if(res==EOF)break;
        p->link = head;
        head = p;    
    }
    return head;   
}
```

Comment: `sizeof(polyPointer)` looks wrong, seeing `polyPointer` is a typedef'd pointer

Comment: Hint: don't cast the return value of `malloc`; hint2: use the object itself as operand of `sizeof`; hint3: don't hide the pointerness of identifiers behind a `typedef`. `struct polyNode *head = malloc(n * sizeof *head);`

Comment: i'm totally done

Answer (score 0):

Your `polyPointer` is, as its name says, a pointer. So if you `malloc(sizeof(polyPointer))` you are allocating only the size of a pointer. But you want to allocate an object, so do 
`malloc(sizeof(*polyPointer))`.

You further check if `fb` was opened with `if(fb==NULL){...`. Luckily `fb` was uinitialized and probaly will not be NULL, but you never called `fopen` for the file.

And I see in your `for` loop that you iterate until `i` is 10 but a) `i` is uninitialized and so could be `-123456` or so, and b) you never check if you have reached the end of the link list. So the last elements printed are undefined (garbage). So change the for loop to: 
`for(i=0; i<10 && A!=NULL; A=A->link, i++)`.

And don't cast the result of `malloc`. It returns a `void` pointer, which is compatible with any pointer type.